# Ajax call to webmethod gives ERROR 500 Internal server error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a web method through ajax call.

**The jQuery code is :**

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "Login.aspx/LoginMethod",
data: { paramtr: "abc" },
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:'json',
success: function (result) {
swal("Done", "User added !", "success");
alert(result);
},
error: function () {
alert('0');
swal("Oops!", "Something went wrong!", "error")
}
});
```

**and the web method code is:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string LoginMethod(string param)
{
string _param = param;
    return "OKDONNE";
}
```

But I am getting Error 500 Internal server error and error function in ajax call gets called alerting '0'.Please help I have tried nearly everything!

Comment: Is asp able to build a parameter list? I think, LoginMethod can't have any arguments. You have to get the parameters elsewhere.

Comment: LoginMethod can take parameters .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this line `data: { paramtr: "abc" },` to `data: { param: "abc" },`.

Because your c# code accepts `param` not `paramtr`.

Comment: i have tried that also but it does not seem to work, still giving the same error

Comment: Internal server error means there is some error at server end. As per your code, I have given the above solution. You should put a break point and debug the code at server, when posting the data from the page. This will help you to resolve your issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info @vivek

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by putting the following line of code :

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ param: 1}),
```

Now everything is working fine without errors . Thanks to @vivek for his inputs

Answer (score 2):

Always ensure your json key is the same as the parameters received by the web method. e.g...

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.id = 'person';
obj.age = 30;

[WebMethod]
public static string savePerson(string id, int age){
    string outcome = "";

    return outcome;
}
```

I figured out after almost a day of error 500